# Add grouping variable to attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector

I have a vector shapefile of river networks, where each reach in the networks has its own row in the attribute table. I want to add a grouping column to the attribute table indicating which network the reach belongs to, e.g.:

a two network example:
[image]

and my attribute table:

[image]

I would like an additional column in the attribute table called "network" which would be filled with 1, 2, ....*n* indicating which network the given reach belongs to (in the example above "network" would be 1 or 2 since there are only two networks), it doesn't matter which network is 1 and which is 2.

Comment: If you have only 2 networks, select all features in one network, and use field calculator to create new field (column) with value 1 and only update selected features checked. After that just invert selection and use field calculator to updated selected to value 2 for the previously created field.

Comment: I should have stated this is just toy data, I am working with many networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Apply a buffer around the line (network) layer and dissolve it. Convert the buffers from [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts).
2. Create a unique `id` on the buffer layer with field calculator and `$id`. Than add this `id` to the line layer with [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) (see screenshot).

*Buffer layer in orange and resulting line layer in black with id added to label the network lines:*
[image]